# sql server 2005 question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to work with sql server 2005, I need server and developer tools.

my database contain 2 million records, 20 tables and 30 users.

what version of sql server 2005 I need ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to learn to write better subject lines. I've noticed this is a habit with you. It's why I downvoted.

SQL Server 2005 Express would work for you. SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition would be good for use by your developers, but cannot be used in production.

Why not use SQL Server 2008? Why start off in the past?

Comment: Well, actually, -1 is a bit harsh. Resetting. But, still. Developer edition is not a valid suggestion other than for actual development. Which you would need to clarify, in that case. =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SQL Server 2005 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx) for free

Answer (score 1):

**Express Edition**

Without knowing the size of your data the Express 
Edition may not be what you require as it has the following limitations:

- 4Gb database size
- 1 CPU
- 1Gb RAM.

**Developer Edition**

Because you are going to have 30 users connecting to this instance, the Developer Edition will be in violation of the Microsoft EULA and you would more than likely need to purchase SQL Server 2005 Standard or Enterprise Edition.

You could however use the Developer edition on your workstation to design and develop the database that will then be deployed onto a Standard or Enterprise edition server.

Hope this helps.

- [Developer Edition Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/developer.aspx)